# Jquery on click return a value and use it in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to calculate the `inc` and get the value returned so I can use it later . I am taking the value from two funcitons . Functions actually work and if I `console.log(inc)` it in a function , i get the value printed . But if I do it outside like you can see in the code, I just get 0, or rather , nothing happens. How can I return the value and use it later in my code ?

The value inc , I get from the clicked buttons + and -. If the buttons get clicked , they go up or down a number in range of -3 to 3 .
[image]

```js
var zoomIn = $('.s-plus');
var zoomOut = $('.s-minus');
var inc = 0;

zoomIn.on('click', function positive() {
  inc = inc + 1;
  if (inc > 3) {
    return inc = inc - 1;
  }
})

zoomOut.on('click', function negative() {
  inc = inc - 1;
  if (inc < -3) {
    return inc = inc + 1;
  }
})

console.log(inc);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-magnifier-container magnify">
  <div class="zoom">
    <span class="s s-plus"><span class="hide">zoom-in</span></span>
    <span class="s s-minus"><span class="hide">zoom-out</span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually fine. However, the `console.log()` is only called once on initialisation. If you want to see the change, move the `console.log()` (or any function that needs to react to the change) to the event handlers.

```js
var zoomIn = $('.s-plus')
var zoomOut = $('.s-minus')
var resize = $('.resize')
var inc = 0

zoomIn.on('click', function positive() {
  inc = inc + 1;
  if (inc > 3) {
    inc = 3;
  }
  
  console.log(inc);
})

zoomOut.on('click', function negative() {
  inc = inc - 1;
  if (inc < -3) {
    inc = -3;
  }
  
  console.log(inc);
})

resize.on('click', function() {
  console.log(inc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-magnifier-container magnify">
  <div class="zoom">
    <span class="s s-plus"><span class="hide">zoom-in</span></span>
    <span class="s s-minus"><span class="hide">zoom-out</span></span>
  </div>
  
  <button class="resize">Resize</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I did do this before but I actualy need to have another function after these two that uses the value "inc" . I used the console.log just to show that this value needs to be used later. When i click the two buttons now , the value stays at 0 .

Comment: That's why I wrote - "(or any function that needs to react to the change)". Replace `console.log()` with whatever function needs those value, and the function will be called with the current one.

Comment: So I would have to write the same function twice ?

Comment: You would call the same function whenever it needs to know that `inc` has changed. The other option is to use polling/observer/setter to call the function when `inc` changes, which is much more difficult.

Comment: "You would call the same function whenever it needs to know that inc has changed." this part i don't understand . I need the value of inc because I want to enlarge the picture or make it smaller dependning on the "inc" . So with every click I need to check the value of "inc" . I know that would work if I made two functions but I wanted to avoid repetiton if possible . So the best way would be to write the function twice for both clicks ?

Comment: If the function for both cases (larger/smaller) is the same, just call the same function in each event handler. If you've got  there's another button that calls a "resize" function (like the one I've added to the answer), it can use `inc` directly.

Comment: I see. This should make it right . I will try it and upvote :)